# Win 10 UWP App: Unable to upload app package to Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-store

I am trying to deploy my windows 10 uwp app to the windows store. I got a validated developer account and everything set up. My app packages have been built and passed all tests of the testing kit. Now I am trying to perform the last step: uploading to the store.

[image: upload app packages...]

The problem is, that the "Upload App Packages..." is greyed out! I tryed to clean the project, selected the project to no avail.

Has anyone got an idea what the problem might be or how to further debug it? As there is not error message I am not certain what is wrong in the first place...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you create the packages first?

Comment: yes, I did create the packages successfully and they are present in APPFOLDER\AppPackages\*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036(v=vs.120).aspx), this option merely opens the Dev center dashboard. Save yourself the trouble and open it directly in your web browser: https://dev.windows.com

To be honest, for some reason I don't even have this option in my Visual Studio (maybe it was removed in VS 2015?). I've always generated the packages from VS then uploaded them with the web browser, without any trouble.

Comment: It is located under: Project -> Store -> ...  but I will try the classic procress then, thank you! Strange that the option is not available for everyone, I am also running Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Goto in Release Configuration and Check .net native tool chain and optimize code then create app package again (Don't forget to associate app to store first)